# Why is the function call happening for a differnet input and segfaulting?

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault

This is my code for finding the longest collatz sequence between 1 and n. And obviously for t test cases. Here, I have also used memoization and thus malloced 'v'. But as the input to the function cycles(int x) goes beyond 4254, ie. 4255, there is something peculiar happening. The function is being input a number 6053452 instead of 4255. And due to this, the program segfaults, as we have only allocated space for 5000000 integers. What have I done wrong?

**Note: The program works pleasantly till n = 4254! (not the factorial)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

    #define RANGE 5000000
    using namespace std;

    int *v = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*RANGE);

    int cycles(int x){
        int c = 1;
        
        
        while(x!=1){
            
            if(v[x]!=0){
                c = c + v[x];
                break;
            }
            
            if(x%2){
                x = 3*x + 1;
            }else{
                x/=2;
            }
            c++;
        }
        
        v[x] = c;
        
        return c;
        
    }


    void solve(int n){
        
        int mx = 0;
        int mx_cnt = 0;
        int c;
        
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            c = cycles(i);
            if(c >= mx_cnt){
                mx = i;
                mx_cnt = c;
            }
            
        }
        
        cout << mx << endl;
        
    }

    int main(){
        
        
        int t,n;

        cin >> t;

        while(t--){

            cin >> n;

            solve(n);


        }
        

        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: place a breakpoint at solve(n) in main().

Comment: Just do `int v[RANGE];` instead of using `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

`v` points to a `malloc`ed array and `malloc` does no initialization. You have `if(v[x]!=0)` and `c = c + v[x];` operating on an uninitialized variables. Embrace C++ and replace the `malloc`ed array with a `std::vector`. `vector` initializes its contents.

This might not be the only bug, just the most obvious.

Correction based on point raised by molbdnilo in the comments: I reached for too complicated a tool. `int v[RANGE];` will allocate and [zero-initialize the array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Static_initialization). Since the array never changes size, a `vector`'s dynamic array is unnecessary. Use `std::array<int, RANGE> v;` and you'll have a zero-initialized fixed-size array and still get useful functions like `at` for debugging.

Comment: Well, i had used fill_n(v,5000000,0) earlier but the result was the same! When I debug it, the segfault occurs at n=4255. If malloc had a problem then none of the cases would work.. but it seems to be working fine for the first 4254 integers.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that you observe is that you access `v` out of bounds. You also use the `malloc`d memory *uninitialized* which makes the program have another problem. Both results in *undefined behavior*.

```
int cycles(int x){
    int c = 1;
        
    while(x!=1){
        if(v[x]!=0){               // <-    x >= RANGE
            c = c + v[x];
            break;
        }
        // ...
```

To find problems like this I suggest using a `vector` instead and, at least when developing the program, use the [`vector::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) bounds checking member function.

```
std::vector<int> v(RANGE);

int cycles(int x){
    int c = 1;
        
    while(x!=1){
        // The below use of `v.at(x)` may result in an exception like:
        // what():  vector::_M_range_check:
        //          __n (which is 6053452) >= this->size() (which is 5000000)

        if(v.at(x)!=0){  
            c = c + v[x];
            break;
        }
        // ...
```

To catch the exception, you could rewrite `main` like this:

```
#include <exception>

int main() {
    int t, n;
    try {
        std::cin >> t;
        while(t--) {
            cin >> n;
            solve(n);
        }
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

If you have a modern 64 bit computer, allocating a lot more shouldn't be a problem. I did this and it solved `4255` fine:

```
constexpr size_t RANGE = 6810137;
```

Comment: yes i could do that but i initially had a stack overflow as the size of my array/vector is around 5 million!

Comment: @YuvrajSakshith  it's most likely ~ 20 MB (5 million * `sizeof(int)`) and the `vector` will most likely put that on the heap, not the stack. The out of bounds access  when you enter `4255` is that `x` becomes `6053452` as I showed in the answer.

Comment: i did that and now I get an error saying: **libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector**

Comment: @YuvrajSakshith Just catch the exception and print out the message and you see something very similar to what I put in the answer.

Comment: is there a way I could have a 5 million int array? I guess by solving that I could solve the problem

Comment: 5 million `int`s is not enough to solve 4255. You need more with your current approach. I increased it to `6810137` and then it solved it just fine.

Comment: Ohh okay. Ill do that

Comment: @YuvrajSakshith Great, but, don't continue using `malloc`. Use `std::vector<int>` instead. It becomes so much easier to do things right.

Comment: But what is still bugging me is, how is this number 6053452 being passed into cycles(int x) when while calling we are passing only 4255? Why does this conversion happen?

Comment: @YuvrajSakshith There's no conversion that I could see. It's all in your algorithm. You could print out the values at certain strategic places in the program to see what it's doing, or use a debugger and set some break points. One good place to start would be in the `while(x != 1)` loop. I'd add: `std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';` there

Comment: @YuvrajSakshith It's not being passed in. `x` was being mauled inside `cycles`.

Comment: My trick for getting to the target with a debugger would be to create a global junk variable and print the junk variable at the end of `main` so it won't be optimized out and then do something like `if (x==4255) { junk++; }` that I can put a breakpoint on. Then I'd step through the function and go looking for where `x` goes out of bounds.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes. One might need some other triggers too. In the case with 4255, it takes 322103 iterations in the `while(x!=1)` loop for it to spike :-)

Comment: And that leads to a side note: With that many iterations the algorithm, if correct, might not be fast enough for an online judge.

Comment: @user4581301 I've no idea about that but the memoization may actually be working. The program answers very quickly - but I don't have anything to compare it with.

Comment: Fast for you, maybe. I'm running the program on a Dorito. You know it, I know it, the judge will be the final arbiter. Asker probably won't lose anything by trying what they've got.